# Ошибка получения готового DTO через Kafka в Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой проблемой: Есть 2 спринг бут приложения. Я пытаюсь передавать готовые DTO из 1 приложения в другое через кафку, но постоянно сталкиваюсь с проблемой: передаю вроде бы все хорошо, но в слушателе, когда пытаюсь получить данные DTO вылезает ошибка:

```
    2022-02-06 15:23:06.433 ERROR 29876 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler   : Backoff none exhausted for posts-0@2589

org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'void com.amar.vkbotservice.configuration.KafkaListenerTest.Listener(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<java.lang.String, com.amar.vkbotservice.dto.PostDto>)' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.amar.vkbotservice.dto.PostDto (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.amar.vkbotservice.dto.PostDto is in unnamed module of loader 'app'); nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.amar.vkbotservice.dto.PostDto (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.amar.vkbotservice.dto.PostDto is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2633) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2603) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2564) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2483) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2405) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2284) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1958) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1353) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1344) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1236) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Restored Stack Trace
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:363) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:92) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:53) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2583) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.amar.vkbotservice.dto.PostDto (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.amar.vkbotservice.dto.PostDto is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.amar.vkbotservice.configuration.KafkaListenerTest.Listener(KafkaListenerTest.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor123.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:169) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:119) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:56) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:347) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:92) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:53) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2583) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
```

Вот листинг класса DTO:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class PostDto {
    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    private Date date;
    private String text;
    private List<String> images;
}
```

Вот так настроен producer и топик:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {
    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String boostrapServers;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, PostDto> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, boostrapServers);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, PostDto> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

}
```

Топик

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaTopicConfig {

    @Bean
    public NewTopic postsTopic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("posts").build();
    }
}
```

А вот настройки Consumer'а, вроде бы все делал по туториалу:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfigTest {
    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String boostrapServers;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, PostDto> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, boostrapServers);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<?> factory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, PostDto> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

}
```

Собственно Listener:

```
@Component
public class KafkaListenerTest {

    @KafkaListener(topics = "posts", groupId = "groupId")
    void Listener(ConsumerRecord<String, PostDto> consumerRecord) {
        PostDto postDto = consumerRecord.value();
        System.out.println(postDto);
    }
}
```

Безусловно, я могу получать из consumerRecord.value() просто json строку своего дто, и дальше, сторонней библиотекой, просто десериализовывать в объект, но неужели из кафки нельзя получить уже готовый объект? Или все же это я что то делаю не так?

Comment: Возможно, не хватает `spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages`

Comment: Разобрался. оказывается, если в Listener аннотации не указать название бина containerFactory, в моем случае containerFactory = "factory", то он использует параметры по умолчанию, а это <String, String>